# Using Tarantool and Postgres together

Tags: postgresql, tarantool

I'm building a project with predicting high load. I need some cache system and Tarantool looks pretty promising for my tasks. I'm curious is it possible to use Tarantool as a cache system (guys said it has some kind of smart cache), but with Postgres in tandem as a main storage, because in future we wanna show some statistics to the client etc and I suspect Tarantool does not have complicated *group by* and join possibilities.

Okay, my question is does Tarantool has possibility to cache and save into Postgres after that in some kind of one transaction, so I never get inconsistency. Sorry for not showing any code here, I just do not have one.

Answer (score 3):

Actually your question is about: how to replicate data from the Master storage to other subsystems.

I can share my experience in this question. I use Postgres with Redis, Elastic search. I just replicate some tables, data into Redis and Elastic. You can find more information about it in *internet.

My installation of PostgreSQL scaled using following rules: Applications use replicas for read, and master is only for write. Geo Search requests go to Redis cluster; Full text search requests go to Elastic cluster.

Back to your topic. You can use any tool, but you also have to think about type of requests. For example: "will it be geosearch?", or "will it be large joins? if so, then it does not work well with Tarantool", anything else?. However, if you have simple Key-Value, so Tarantool is good here.

PS

Also I can suggest to read about cache patterns: https://www.computerweekly.com/feature/Write-through-write-around-write-back-Cache-explained

"* For example: https://github.com/bucardo/bucardo"

Answer (score 1):

The Tarantool manual https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.2/reference/reference_rock/dbms/
describes how to invoke PostgreSQL from the Tarantool application server. There is no consistency guarantee, for example the application program would have to do rollback on a Tarantool database transaction and a separate rollback on a PostgreSQL database transaction, and ensure they both worked.